# Add extra values to JQuery Datepicker with asp.net fix

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, validation

I've got an ASP.NET page that has a box with a Validation and the JQuery Datepicker assigned to it. I had the same error as described art https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/jquery-en/qJAvJ3TtwFo and implemented the fix, but now I want to add the following lines to it

```
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
showOn: "button",
buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
buttonImageOnly: true,
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
```

This is my current code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(".datePicker").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { } }); 
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm supposed to put it please?

Comment: I ended up editing the lines in my javascript file to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".datePicker").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { },
       changeMonth: true,
       changeYear: true,
       showOn: "button",
       buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
       buttonImageOnly: true,
       dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }); 
</script>
```